# Prevent swagger from using MessageSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, internationalization, openapi

I'm using OpenApi generator https://openapi-generator.tech/ to generate the REST API interfaces that will be used in a SpringBoot 6 based service.
Below is an excerpt from an API definition (registration.yml):

```
...
paths:
  /registration/register:
    post:
      description: Register a user
      operationId: registerUser
      tags:
        - registration
...
```

I've noticed that as soon as the Swagger webpage (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html) opens it starts looking for the messages via `MessageSource.resolveCode()`.
It uses the text from the `description` field **'Register a user'** as a message code to find the corresponding message text via `MessageSource.resolveCode()`
However as can be seen above such messages are already text messages and aren't message codes. Yes, they are hard-coded but I'm fine with that.
Is it possible to configure it so that **Swagger** doesn't search those messages?

Not sure whether it helps but here is the top of the stack when `MessageSource.resolveCode()` is called in such a situation:

```
resolveCode:77, DBMessageSource
resolveCodeWithoutArguments:368, AbstractMessageSource (org.springframework.context.support)
getMessageInternal:212, AbstractMessageSource (org.springframework.context.support)
getMessage:153, AbstractMessageSource (org.springframework.context.support)
resolve:88, PropertyResolverUtils (org.springdoc.core.utils)
parse:130, OperationService (org.springdoc.core.service)
calculatePath:459, AbstractOpenApiResource (org.springdoc.api)
calculatePath:654, AbstractOpenApiResource (org.springdoc.api)
lambda$calculatePath$11:219, OpenApiResource (org.springdoc.webmvc.api)
...
```

The option:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
```

in

```
application.yml
```

Disables the swagger webpage completely which I don't need

Answer (score 0):

The option is yet available on solves the problem

```
springdoc:
  disable-i18n: true
```